# Launch browser in kiosk mode from Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

"Simple question":

Is it possible to launch the default browser from a Windows Store App directly in kiosk mode if applicable?

I doubt that this is possible via

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: Are you asking: "If my app is running in kiosk mode, can I still start a browser?" If so, try it. Or are you asking "Can a store app that is not running in kiosk mode open a browser that is running in kiosk mode?" The answer to that question is no.

Comment: Open a browser in kiosk mode from an app that is not running in kiosk mode.

Comment: Unless we are talking about a different kind of kiosk mode (I'm talking about this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx), it should be obvious that what you want is impossible.

Comment: I hope that's not possible. Just host the web browser in your kiosk application. The 8.1 webview is far more capable than the support in 8.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten, we are talking about different kiosk mode. I am talking about the implemented kiosk mode in browsers. 

The WebView still doesn't support what I want to achieve. But that's not the topic.